# SQL subtract from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different queries from two tables. The first query I have is:

```
select sum(total_amount) as total_amount, supplier_name 
from tbL_supplierAccountLedger 
where DATE >= '2017-01-01' and DATE <= '2017-12-31'  group by supplier_name
```

The output of this is

```
Total Amount | Supplier name

4000               A
5000               B
8000               C
9000               D
```

Here is my another query with different tablename

```
SELECT SUM(RET_AMOUNT)as returnamount, SUPPLIER_NAME  
FROM tbl_PurchaseReturns
where CAST(date as DATE) >= '2017-01-01' and 
CAST(date as DATE) <= '2017-12-31'
group by SUPPLIER_NAME
```

The output of this is

```
Return Amount | Supplier name

1000               A
2000               B
500                C
```

I want a query that automatically subtracts table B from table A.
Below is the expected output.

```
total amount | Supplier Name 
3000             A 
3000             B 
7500             C 
9000             D
```

Comment: Please provide your desired output

Comment: total amount | Supplier Name

3000  A
3000  B
7500                        C
9000  D

Answer (score 3):

use derived query and union both result, with the RET_AMOUNT of tbl_PurchaseReturns as negative value. And finally group by supplier_name

```
SELECT SUM(total_amount), supplier_name 
FROM
(

    SELECT sum(total_amount) as total_amount, supplier_name 
    from   tbL_supplierAccountLedger 
    where  DATE >= '2017-01-01' and DATE <= '2017-12-31'  
    group by supplier_name 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(-RET_AMOUNT) as returnamount, supplier_name 
    FROM   tbl_PurchaseReturns
    where  CAST(date as DATE) >= '2017-01-01' 
    and    CAST(date as DATE) <= '2017-12-31'
    group by supplier_name 

) AS D
GROUP BY supplier_name
```

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for. Great! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do the `JOIN`s

```
SELECT s.supplier_name, 
       r.total_amount - coalesce(returnamount, 0) as amount from
(
    SELECT supplier_name , SUM(total_amount) as total_amount
    FROM tbL_supplierAccountLedger 
    WHERE ...  
    GROUP BY supplier_name 
)s LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT SUPPLIER_NAME , SUM(RET_AMOUNT)as returnamount
     FROM tbl_PurchaseReturns
     WHERE ...
     GROUP BY SUPPLIER_NAME
) r on r.SUPPLIER_NAME= s.supplier_name
```